# How to add custom menu in ag-grid

Tags: angular-material, ag-grid

I have created a list component using ag-grid and I'm also using angular material for other components. On my list component I also need add a column with a menu and I know in angular material we have menu item with icon as in below screenshot, how can I add this menu icon on ag-grid table column?

[image: Menu Image]

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/ What issues did you come across?

Comment: @Fletch I am able to add the angular materia menu anywhere outside but when adding it in cell renderer I facing compile error on mat-menu.

Comment: please could you reproduce the errors in a stack blitz so we can help you?

Comment: @Fletch here is the URL to stack blitz, it seems material menu is not recognized under cell renderer or not sure if something is done wrong here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ry9zqn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  Are you trying to get a cell with a menu where the user can edit the cell content?  Is this more what you are hoping for?  (But with a material menu) https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/cell-editors/#example-dynamic-editor-component

Comment: @Fletch that's right. I'm trying to get a cell with menu using material menu. But not for the cell editing it's for performing various other actions like viewing the details of the selected records, viewing graphs related to the selected records , for which menus on each record would be suitable option rather than having checkbox.